# userInterfaceIdiom always indicate iPhone

Tags: ios

I added the following code to AppDelegate:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"iPhone found");
} else {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"iPad found");
}
```

The userInterfaceIdiom always equal to UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone when running on iPad 2.  My iPad 2 is running on iOS 6.1.3.

I cannot find out what the problem is.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Targeted Devices should be **Universal**,

[image]

Comment: Try this for non-universal app. `BOOL isiPad = [[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPad"];`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)

if (!IS_IPAD) {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"iPhone found");
} else {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"iPad found");
}
```